# Why does my JPA @ManyToOne relationship return an empty array?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postman

I'm creating a REST API. When I send the Student with their Grades from Postman, it seems like my Java Spring Boot backend receives it and saves it in the database. The issue arises when I call what I saved in the database from Postman because it's returning the student and an empty array of grades.

[backend java springboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYArU.jpg)

[Post Postman with url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL3ux.jpg)

[Get Postman with url and empty array of grades](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waGKa.jpg)

I have been removing the 'mappedBy' annotation from my Student class, and it works, but it creates a new table in the database, and that's not the goal of my project. My intention is to receive the student and their grades through the GET request in Postman.

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "estudiante", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER).

[backend without mappedBy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVAAU.jpg)

[Post postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAJ1y.jpg)

[Get Postman with Array 'student' and 'grades' filled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPQ8B.jpg)

[Extra table created in PostgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG75B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `mappedBy = "estudiante",` in the  @OneToMany relationship
Refer [Hibernate collections-bidirectional-bag](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-bidirectional-bag)

For example if
**Note need to be owning side of the bidirectional bag association then @OneToMany need to configure with mappedBy attribute**  else not needed.

Estudiante

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Estudiante")
@Getter 
@Setter 
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Estudiante {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "estudiante_id")
    private List<Note> notes;
}
```

Note:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Note")
@Getter 
@Setter 
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Note {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String materia;
    private String calificacion;

    @ManyToOne
    private Estudiante estudiante;
}
```